# Java dynamic method return type

Tags: java, spring, arraylist

**EDIT** *I should have originally mentioned this for anyone that tried to help answer this question, but this method (`getList(String variable)` on File1.java) is actually a RESTful endpoint that gets called when the client application sends a GET request to whatever path is on the calling method's class.*

I have a method that takes a string variable as an argument. The functionality I'm trying to achieve is that, based on the value of that string variable, the method will construct 1 of two different Lists, and return that list. Is this possible? I tried using a generic method like the person in the 3rd answer down from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191536/dynamic-return-type-in-java-method), but I'm probably not implementing it correctly because I'm getting a `Type parameter [GenericType] not a class or parameterized type whose raw type is a class` IllegalArgumentException. Here's my code and how far I got:

File1.java - some things omitted for brevity

```
@Component
public class File1{

    private File2 file2;

    @Autowired
    private File1(File2 file2) {
        this.file2 = file2;
    }

    public <GenericType> GenericType getList(String variable) {
       return (GenericType)this.file2.getList(variable);
    }
}
```

File2.java - some things omitted for brevity

```
@Component
public class File2 {
    public <GenericType> GenericType getList(String variable) {
           List<SomeClass> listA = new ArrayList<>();
           List<SomeOtherClass> listB = new ArrayList<>();
        if(variable.equals("something")) {
           //build listA...
        }
        else {
           //build listB instead...
        }
        if(variable.equals("something"))
           return (GenericType) listA;
        else
           return (GenericType) listB;
    }
}
```

SomeClass.java

```
public class SomeClass{
    public String string;
    public List<NestedList1> nestedList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<NestedList2> nestedList2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public SomeClass(String string, List<NestedList1> nestedList1 , List<NestedList2> nestedList2) {
        this.string= string;
        this.nestedList1 = nestedList1 ;
        this.nestedList2 = nestedList2 ;
    }
}
```

SomeOtherClass.java

```
public class SomeOtherClass{
    public String string;
    public List<NestedList3> nestedList3 = new ArrayList<>();

    public SomeOtherClass(String string, List<NestedList3> nestedList3) {
        this.string = string;
        this.nestedList3 = nestedList3;
    }
}
```

The @component and @autowired annotations are just spring configuration stuff so you can just ignore it as it is not related to the question. Anyways, I feel like this is a lot simpler than I'm making out to be, but I'm still pretty new to Java and this is my 1st time using generic methods. If it helps, the lists that are being returned are not, themselves, dynamic. This method should only and always return 1 of these two specific lists.

Comment: that's the longest cast I ever saw

Comment: It is kind of redundant. I can edit it but that's still not solving my original problem.

Comment: in your case, I would consider using a wildcard `?` like `list<?>`. And yes, `(List<? extends SomeOtherClass>)(List<SomeOtherClass>)` is totally redundant

Comment: What does the line that calls `File1.getList()` look like, including any relevant type declaration?

Comment: @Douglas I omitted this thinking it wouldn't be relevant, but in context, this would actually be a restful endpoint I've set up. A GET request to be exact. There is a path defined on this class, and if the user hits this endpoint with a GET request, that method gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this trick to work, Java needs to have a way, somehow, to figure out what type `GenericType` actually is. When you call a method explicitly in code and assign its result to a variable, as in the answer you linked to, it can infer that `GenericType` is the type of the variable. That's done at compile time, and Java's fine with it.

A restful endpoint such as you're making doesn't have that. Your REST provider has to figure out the type at runtime using reflection, and the information needed to do that just isn't there. For one thing there's no non-reflective in-code call to infer type information from, and for another type erasure would discard it during compilation anyway.

Fortunately, there's actually no need for this anyway. Both of your possible return values are of type `List`. Just declare the method as returning `List`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it wasn't relevant, but maybe I should have mentioned that this was a restful endpoint in my question, and not just any java application.

Simply changing the endpoint's return type to the general `List` type worked.

Answer (score 1):

Java cannot do that (in general).

The usage would be:

```
List<?> list = file1.getList(s);
```

and then dynamically check the content.

For this it would be nice to have the class not in the list elements only (which could be null), but in the List itself.

In general make a class containing both differently typed lists, and return that, one of the lists being empty.